# Excel Formula/ VBA code : To lookup value horizontally and pull the entire column ( multiple values)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a huge data. Need to look up data horizontally, and pull/extract all the multiple rows associated with the same column.

Example

Sheet 1 : Row 1has headers till Column z
Each Rows/columns has data associated with that header

Column A - Name 
Column B - Address 
Column C - Company    Etc....
Column Z

Sheet 2: A1 has data like "Company".

I need to look for "Company" in the sheet1 header and pull the entire column in sheet 2 Column A.

Sheet 2 : B1 has data like "Name"

I need to look for "Name" in the sheet1 header and pull the entire column in sheet 2 column B.

is there any VBA code/ formula to pull this?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the structure of your workbook

```
Code = YourSearchedItem

Set TargetCell = Range("A:A").Find(What:=Code)

CurrRow = TargetCell.Row    ' Will Return Row number
```